# Laravel JQuery AJAX ISSUE when URL has a trailing slash

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, url

I am getting **404 Not Found** error when using **AJAX call in Laravel**

URL

```
var url = "{{config('app.url')}}/profile/get/";
```

Route

```
Route::post('/profile/get','StaffController@show');
```

When the above URL is passed to AJAX call, it throws **404 Not Found**

```
 $.post(url, {"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"}, function( msg ){
    console.log( msg );
  });
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: If you manually remove the slash from the link, does it work correctly? Laravel should try to strip trailing slashes and redirect to the canonical route.

Comment: Thanks John, It worked when I removed the trailing slash. But however, didn't work when I created a route with the trailing slash. Thanks for your time though

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23) on laravel. It looks like trailing slash doesn't match routes in Laravel.

When I removed the trailing slash from the URL, it worked like a charm.

However, when I added a new route with the trailing slash, it didn't help.

```
Route::post('/profile/get/','StaffController@show');
```

I am using **Laravel Framework 5.4.36**

Also, 
**Google webmaster blog** states that some websites treat URLs with and ending slash like a directory while without endling slash like a file

```
http://example.com/foo/ (with trailing slash, conventionally a directory)
http://example.com/foo (without trailing slash, conventionally a file)
```

[see here](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html)